# Unknown column in where clause when using AS

Tags: mysql

I have simple SQL :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bdate, CURDATE()) as age, id, bdate 
from  my_table
where age between 20 and 30
```

I got this error :

> Unknown column 'age' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use alias in the `where clause` you need to reuse the formula for the alias in where clause or use `having clause` or use outer query

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bdate, CURDATE()) as age, id, bdate 
from  my_table
having age between 20 and 30
```

OR

```
select * from  (
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bdate, CURDATE()) as age, id, bdate 
 from  my_table
)x
where age between 20 and 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are not available in a `WHERE` clause in MySQL.

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. 
>   **[MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)**

You have to use

```
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bdate, CURDATE())  BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```